# P-Value in one vs two sided tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value

Let's assume we have a right one-sided test with a p-value of 0.03 and a positive test statistical value. Now let's perform a two-sided test with the same datums. Are we going to reject H0?
The significance level is 5%, the test could be either Z or T with one population, so the distribution is symmetric.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's the significance level? Is the test statistic continuous? Is its distribution symmetric?

Comment: What test do you have in mind ?

Comment: Sorry, the significance level is 5%, I test could be either Z or T with one population, so the distribution is symmetric.

Comment: I take it this is a class or self-study assignment ?

Comment: It's from class, I want to understand the answer

Comment: Please, 1) Add the self-study tag to your question. 2) Add the additional details from the comments to the question.  3) Let us know how far you got in answering the question.  What is your thought process?  A diagram like this, from your text book, may guide your thoughts:  [i0.wp.com/statisticsbyjim.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/t_dist_prob.png](https://i0.wp.com/statisticsbyjim.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/t_dist_prob.png)

Comment: Done. I saw the answer and it said that the pvalue of a one-sided distribution is half the pvalue of a two-sided one, and therefore we won't reject H0 for the two-sided test. I'm having a hard time understanding it and perhaps a diagram with the pvalue could help.

Comment: Well, look at the diagram I linked to.  For a one-sided test, the red area is c. 0.03.  But what about for a two-sided test ?

Comment: It should be 0.06, but doesn't it mean we get 0.03 for each side, and then we still reject H0? (Because the red area on the side the original test was on didn't actually change)

Comment: No, for the two-sided test, you use 0.03 + 0.03 = 0.06 , because you are using the red area in both tails.

Comment: I think you didn't get me. Let's say we have a right one-sided test with a pvalue of 0.03 (=the red area is 0.03). Now let's make a two-sided test with the same datums (now the pvalue is 0.06 = the red area). But, each side in a two sided test get's a half of pvalue (0.03) and then the right red area of the two-sided test is identical to the right one-sided test (because we gave half to each side) which means we still reject H0 (because we rejected H0 in the one-sided test and the areas are identical). What am I missing here?

Comment: It's just that when you are conducting a two-sided test, you have to use both tails. Because you don't know if you should use the right tail or the left tail.

Answer (score 2):

The two-sided p-value in the question will be 0.06, insignificant at 5% level, as two probabilities 0.03 have to be added from both sides. But this was apparently clear already.

The more interesting question is, how is it possible and how can it be reasonable that the same data reject the $H_0$ when testing one-sided, but don't reject when testing two-sided?

The reason is that in general the significance level is actually a *performance characteristic* of the test. The idea is that if you test a lot of times at level 5% in situations in which the null hypothesis is true, 5% of the tests will (wrongly) reject the null hypothesis.

Now if you test one-sided, you can only reject if the test statistic is too large (say). You will therefore reject if the statistic is so high that it is in the region of the expected 5% highest values. If you test two-sided, you will reject both if the tests statistic is too large and if it is too small. Now it should be clear that you cannot always reject the two-sided test if the one-sided tests rejects. Because if you did so, as the two-sided test is symmetric, you'd need to reject as often on the negative side, and that would give you 10% rejections, but you want to test at 5% level, so that'd be too much.

In fact, in order to reach a rejection probability of 5% for the two-sided test, you can only afford to reject half the time on the positive side than the one-sided test would reject. The two-sided test has more options to reject (namely on both sides), so it needs to reject less often on either side in order to achieve the same overall level of 5%.

"Translated" into p-values this means that the p-value, if observing on the right side, should be smaller than 5% *only half the time* for the two-sided test than for the one-sided test. This is achieved by multiplying the one-sided p-value by 2.